# KendoUI menu/navigation with fixed width

Tags: menu, kendo-ui, navigation, fixed-width

Is there a way to set `fixed width` to KendoUI menu elements?

(I could not find a solution in the official documentation http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/menu, but before I start butchering the DOM with cutsom CSS, I wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything.)

http://plnkr.co/edit/EJJ2wX?p=preview

Thanks,
--iM